# Graph is not generating properly in shiny only a single bar is shown in graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have imported the dataset = students for generating the  reactive plots  but proper plot is not generated .I am using ggplot for plots so could you
please tell me whats wrong in my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- navbarPage("A SHINY APP!! ",
         tabPanel("Plots",headerPanel("Different plots of data"),
          sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("x.col","x.variable",choices=names(students))
                           ),
                   mainPanel(plotOutput("histPlot")))
                           )
                        )


server <- function(input, output) {
         plot <- reactive({ ggplot(students,aes(x=input$x.col))
                         })
         output$histPlot <- renderPlot({
                 plot() + geom_histogram(stat = "count",bins = 30)
                                  })
                        }


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with get() function like the following:

```
ggplot(students, aes(x = get(input$x.col)))
```